# strtotime converting on wrong timezone

Tags: php, strtotime

I am facing the following problem when converting a date value using strtotime().
If I do: `strtotime('1/1/2019')` the output would be `1546293600 -> 31.12.2018 @ 10:00pm (UTC)`

- If I do: `date_default_timezone_get()` the output is `Europe/Bucharest`
- In my php.ini file (of my hosting account), the timezone is set to `date.timezone="Europe/Helsinki"`

I have following two questions.

1. Shouldn't `date_default_timezone_get()` output what it is configured
   in my hosting accounts php.ini file? (the
   `date_default_timezone_set()` is not being used)?
2. Why the `strtotime()` conversion result is on GMT-2 timezone? It is
   my understanding that if there is no timestamp supplied, the
   conversion should be done on the current time (which should be
   GMT+2, either Helsinki or Bucharest)?

If I do `date_default_timezone_set('UTC')` the conversion result of `strtotime('1/1/2019)` is done correctly (on GMT+2).

Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure that `date_default_timezone_set()` isn't being called in another part of the application? Maybe your file includes another file, which does set it? Are you using any third party PHP libraries for example which may have done this?

Comment: Your timezone is set to Bucharest (or Helsinki or whatever), so "1/1/2019" is being interpreted as being in that timezone. When converted from there to UTC, that's a difference of 2 hours. Pretty simple.

Comment: @deceze both Bucharest and Helsinki time zones are at GMT+2, why a difference of -2? The `strtotime()` specification is clearly stating that the result is a timestamp calculated based on the timezone, so if there is no timezone specified, then the conversion will be done based on the current timezone which should be Bucharest time zone( according to `date_default_timezone_get()`), but the result is not on the Bucharest time zone.

Comment: "1/1/2019 00:00 GMT+2" equals "31.12.2018 @ 10:00pm (UTC)". They refer to the same point in time, you're just looking at it in different timezones. GMT+2 is *two hours ahead*, so UTC is *two hours behind*.

Comment: @deceze I have to apologize, but I cannot see your point. From the strtotime doc `Each parameter of this function uses the default time zone unless a time zone is specified in that parameter.` since I am not specifying any time zone, I am expecting the conversion to be done on the default time zone which in my case is Bucharest. How am I interpreting this in the wrong way? (I'm feeling dumb right now :) )

Comment: Your timestamp *is* being interpreted in the timezone Bucharest! And then you get a UNIX timestamp. And then you have that UNIX timestamp be formatted to a UTC timestamp. In the Bucharest → UTC conversion, there's a two hour difference. If you format that UNIX timestamp into a Bucharest timezone timestamp, you'll see your original Bucharest time.

Comment: Which version of PHP are you using?

Comment: @DavidLemon PHP 5.4

Answer (score 0):

There may be some reasons why this is happening and we can't tell you why, because we don't know your application, since it may somewhere change the time zone at runtime.

Instead you should stop using `strtotime` and embrace object oriented [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.datetime.php) functions.

Using `DateTime` you can define your date along with its time zone:

```
// local time
$date = new \DateTimeImmutable('1/1/2019', new \DateTimeZone('Europe/Bucharest'));
echo $date->format('U > d.m.Y (e)') , '<br>';

// convert to UTC
echo $date->setTimeZone(new \DateTimeZone('UTC'))->format('U > d.m.Y (e)');
```

The library is quite powerful and much more verbose than operating on strings and unix timestamps.

Comment: Thank you for the alternative, but in my case changing the function is not an option. It is a very old application and I would have to change it everywhere. I am looking to understand why the strtotime is returning something else than what I expect, because I am not specifying any time zones in the functions parameter and I am expecting it to make the conversion based on the default timezone which is Bucharest (The call to `strtotime()` is done right after the `date_default_timezone_get()` so I cannot see how the time zone can change from one line to another)

Answer (score 0):

Provide hour and timezone to the function using the full IS0 8601 format `2019-01-01T12:00:00+00:00`. That way you will get the correct timestamp in UTC. If you won't use the hour I recommend to use 12 AM.

In the following example I will use a numeric date array to build this string

```
//   [Y,m,d]
$date = [2019,1,1];
for($i=1; $i<3; $i++){
  $date[$i] = str_pad($date[$i],2,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT);
}
$t1 = strtotime(implode('-',$date).'T12:00:00+00:00');
echo date('r',$t1);
//=>Tue, 01 Jan 2019 12:00:00 +0000
```